# audio calls using webrtc

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I'm looking for code samples for implementing only **audio** calls using webrtc, all what I found was a documentation and code samples only for video calls.

I need a code sample for testing the service and looking for scalability possibilities.

can anyone help? and let me know if there is such a free service providers that matches my requirement

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, implementing audio-only calls with WebRTC is simpler than it might seem. Essentially, you just modify the standard WebRTC setup to request only audio tracks. Use ´navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })´ to obtain the audio stream and then proceed as you would with a regular WebRTC setup, ignoring video-related parts.

For testing scalability, you might want to consider services like Twilio or Agora, as they offer robust WebRTC solutions and are quite scalable. These platforms aren't entirely free, but they usually have free tiers or trial credits which could suit your initial testing needs.

In short, just tweak the standard WebRTC example by excluding the video parts, and you're good to go for an audio-only setup!

Comment: thank you, I thought it would be a bit more complicated :)